# Documenting and consuming Architecture Decision Records in TFS

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, tfs, architecture

This pertains to Lightweight Architecture Decision Records and its usage in TFS with consumer tools in TFS/Powershell.

Based on what exists today
https://github.com/npryce/adr-tools

I wanted to find if there is a corresponding .NET library or project for usage  in TFS.

Comment: I'm not sure if I totally got your point. Your question seems asking if a 3-party tool/extension have support  for  corresponding .NET project. TFS is a source control system absolutely different with powershell. Why you use TFS/Powershell?  Besides, this question is more related to that extension, seems not  related to TFS.

Answer (score 1):

No that I know of.

The tool you reference simply creates some formatted text files; converting similar bash scripts to Powershell is not that hard, so you can do it and share the result with the community publishing your repo.

If you want to create custom work items to track this information, you can do as well. There is plenty of sample code around like [Igor's Powershell Cmdlets](https://github.com/igoravl/tfscmdlets).